# Inference on openvino model returns only scores

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, intel, openvino, movidius

My task is to perform inference for face detection using Intel Movidius and Raspberry Pi. The error is that the model only returns "Scores" -> (1, 3000, 2) and not "Boxes".

Steps:
On my local machine, I trained several models(mb1-ssd, mb1-ssd-lite, vgg16-ssd) from the repository https://github.com/qfgaohao/pytorch-ssd and converted them to onnx. Then, using open vino model optimizer from openvinotoolkit = 2020.1, I obtained the '.bin', '.xml' files for each model.
Then, using the obtained files, I performed the infference on the Rasberry Pi and hit the mentioned error.

Note: The inference works using pretrained face detection models from model zoo, the only difference I found looking at the .xml files and my .xml files is that the last layer, "Detection output" is missing. However, when I visualize the .xml file using netron, the conversion seems to be correct.

Link to repo: https://github.com/cocacola0/bsc_thesis

Comment: In your repository I see that you use OpenCV's API for inference, not OpenVINO's. Is that by definition or can you switch to native OV? Also are you tied to the 2020.1 version of OV? Is't pretty old now and I suggest switching to the 2022.1 release instead. Just try 'pip install openvino' and you sould be able to start testing the newest release and the newest API.

Comment: Intel movidius is not supported in the latest openvino packages, 2020.1 is the last version that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVINO™ 2020.3 release is the last OpenVINO™ version that supports Intel® Movidius™ Neural Compute Stick powered by the Intel® Movidius™ Myriad™ 2.

Use [ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/2020.3/models/public/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco.md) and [ssdlite_mobilenet_v2](https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/blob/2020.3/models/public/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2/ssdlite_mobilenet_v2.md), alternative models that are available in Open Model Zoo. Both models are working well with your code.